# jQuery ajax: call done when request fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I'm trying to synchronize my ajax request using promises:
My current code is this simple:

```
    var ajax = undefined;

    $.ajax({
                type: 'put',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                successs: function () {

                },
                error: function () {

                }

            }).done(function () {
                alert('done');
            });
```

This works fine as long as the ajax call is successful (statuscode 200) but when a call fails (e.g trhow an invalid url), the done isn't called anymore.
How can I execute done, even if the ajax request fails=

Stefan

Comment: you can try using `.complete` callback which will execute whether the ajax request fails or succeed.

Comment: Anyway, you spelt success wrong. Very sssibilantly.

Comment: where did I spell success wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of options for you:

Call the same function on success or failure. Functions don't *have* to be anonymous and defined inline, you can define them separately with names and reference them accordingly.

In your snippet, you're using both the older `success` (although with an extra `s` at the end) and `error` *and* the newer `done`, which means you're defining two different callbacks for success (`success` and `done`). Just one is sufficient.

Here's an example using `success` and `error`, passing `null` into the handler on `error`:

```
var ajax = undefined;

$.ajax({
    type:    'put',
    url:     url,
    data:    data,
    cache:   false,
    success: handler,
    error:   function() {
        handler(null);
    }
});

function handler() {
    alert("Done");
}
```

Or using `done` and `fail`:

```
var ajax = undefined;

$.ajax({
    type:    'put',
    url:     url,
    data:    data,
    cache:   false
}).done(handler).fail(function() {
    handler(null);
});

function handler() {
    alert("Done");
}
```

Alternately (or in combination), there's the `complete` callback (the one you specify in options) and the `always` callback (in the `done` and `fail` style), which are called regardless of success or failure (after the success or failure callbacks are done):

`complete`:

```
var ajax = undefined;

$.ajax({
    type:    'put',
    url:     url,
    data:    data,
    cache:   false,
    success: handler,
    error:   function() {
        handler(null);
    },
    complete: function() {
        alert("Always called (after success/error)");
    }
});

function handler() {
    alert("Done");
}
```

`always`:

```
var ajax = undefined;

$.ajax({
    type:    'put',
    url:     url,
    data:    data,
    cache:   false
}).done(handler).fail(function() {
    handler(null);
}).always(function() {
    alert("Always called (after done/fail)");
});

function handler() {
    alert("Done");
}
```

Comment: Omg how did you write all that... +1 by me :D

Comment: always was the function, I was looking for.

Comment: @Stefan: Cool, glad that helped! The documentation for that part of things is here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `done` function, you can use `complete` setting:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'put',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    successs: function () {

    },
    error: function () {

    }
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Done");

});
```

`complete` function executes after `success` or `error`.  Have a look at [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation for more details.

If you do not care about actual `success` and `error` callbacks and only want to do something once the call completes, regardless of the result, then omit `success` and `error` settings completely.

Comment: Asking to explain the downvote probably will not elicit any response.

Comment: @Alison Someobdy downvoted my answer, and I'm curious as to why.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for done

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function () {
       alert('success');
    },
    error: function () {
       alert('error');
    },
    complete: function(){
       alert('complete');
    }
 });
```

Comment: No, I don't suppose you did